Module import error for PYTHON_PYLINT when using super-linter/super-linter@v6.7.0
I've been working on getting super-linter within a GitHub Action to accept my recent Python project import for a while now without success. I am using py3langid to detect English language in a pretty basic Caesar Cipher implementation.
The linting error is:
PYTHON_PYLINT
2024-07-20 21:05:46 [INFO]   Linting PYTHON_PYLINT items...
Error: -20 21:05:47 [ERROR]   Found errors when linting PYTHON_PYLINT. Exit code: 1.
2024-07-20 21:05:47 [INFO]   Command output for PYTHON_PYLINT:
------
************* Module cipher
caesar_cipher/cipher.py:3:0: E0401: Unable to import 'py3langid.langid' (import-error)
-----------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 8.91/10
------

Top of cipher.py
"""Caesar Cipher implementation"""

from py3langid.langid import MODEL_FILE, LanguageIdentifier

...

Folder structure (shortened for brevity)
~/Projects/cryptography/
    .git
    .github/
        workflows/
            tests.yml
    ...
    caesar_ciper/
        cipher.py
        test_cipher.py
    ...
    __init__.py
    requirements.txt

tests.yml
---
name: Test project
on: push
permissions: read-all
jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Lint
        uses: super-linter/super-linter@v6.7.0
        env:
          # To report GitHub Actions status checks
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  test:
    needs: lint
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Install Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: "3.10"
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Run tests
        run: pytest

I had not used pylint locally before receiving this error. After it appeared I ran
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/data cytopia/pylint .

and got the following error
************* Module .
__init__.py:1:0: F0010: error while code parsing: Unable to load file __init__.py:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '__init__.py' (parse-error)

After adding ~/Projects/cryptography/__init__.py, pylint ran fine locally without any errors, but my remote workflow still fails with the same error as originally stated.
Any idea what I could be doing wrong? Thanks
EDIT
I also tried creating a .pylintrc on the remote GitHub Actions runner using this SO question to populate the file
PyLint "Unable to import" error - how to set PYTHONPATH?
setting ~/.pylintrc to the following didn't effect the super-linter result
[MASTER]
init-hook='import sys; sys.path.append("./")'

EDIT 2
Tried to update PYTHONPATH on the runner to include the working directory
...
- name: Set PYTHONPATH
  run: export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${pwd}
...

This also hasn't helped to resolve the linting error
EDIT 3
As per @Azeem suggestion I tried adding the following to tests.yml under lint
...
steps
...
  - name: Create .pylintrc  # <- this
    run: echo "[MASTER]" > ~/.pylintrc && echo "init-hook='import sys; sys.path.append("./")'" >> ~/.pylintrc  # <- this
  - name: Lint
    uses: super-linter/super-linter@v6.7.0
    env:
      PYTHON_PYLINT_CONFIG_FILE: ~/.pylintrc    # <- this
      # To report GitHub Actions status checks
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

This is the error that came back
[FATAL]     -> PYTHON_PYLINT_LINTER_RULES rules file (/action/lib/.automation/~/.pylintrc) doesn't exist. Terminating...

Does anyone have any more ideas? I'm not even coding the project any more, just fighting the linter. I might have to open an issue on GitHub.
Thanks to @Azeem for chipping in
Read error again and tried to set location .pylintrc to /action/lib/.automation/.pylintrc which also failed
/home/runner/work/_temp/91c876a5-f511-4156-91ca-5e23ad639603.sh: line 1: /action/lib/.automation/.pylintrc: No such file or directory


For testing, add the lint step at the end of your second job and see if that works.

That hasn't made any difference, same error

Try adding PYTHON_PYLINT_CONFIG_FILE: .pylintrc under env of super-linter. See https://github.com/super-linter/super-linter?tab=readme-ov-file#configure-super-linter. The default for PYTHON_PYLINT_CONFIG_FILE is .python-lint.

Thanks Azeem but this hasn't worked either, unless the way I'm adding it is not correct. See EDIT 3 in the Q, Thanks for your efforts

Sure, no problem. If you could share a public repo as an MCVE that'd be very helpful to look into it in detail and iterate quickly.

https://github.com/sedexdev/cryptography - many thanks :)

Admittedly this is not a great answer as the problem still exists, I have worked around it and stopped using super-linter due to trying so many options and getting nowhere.
I have instead installed pylint in my project as well as added raven-actions/actionlint@v2 as a separate step in my workflow.
The linting part of my CI automation now looks like this:
---
name: Linting
on: push
permissions: read-all
jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Install Python
        uses: ./.github/actions/install-py/
      - name: Run pylint
        run: pylint ./**/*.py
      - name: Run actionlint
        uses: raven-actions/actionlint@v2
        with:
          files: ".github/workflows/*.yml"

No more linting errors, and runs much faster as well! I acknowledge this is not an answer to the original issue, but I can sleep in peace now!

After running into multiple issues with your fork, I also started to think along the lines of using pylint directly instead of super-linter. The time super-linter takes to set up is surely not good.
